# display array from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i new in javascript + nodejs

i want display array in javascript from nodejs..

this result from node.js (i use JSON.stringify())

> [{"id":"i01","name":"jack","phone":"123123"},{"id":"i02","name":"john","phone":"123123"},{"id":"i03","name":"jane","phone":"123123"}]

i want display that array like this

> id    |   name     | phone
>   ---+-------+----------
>
> i01  | jack |123123
>
> i02  | john |123123
>
> i03  | jane |123123

how can i achive what i want ?

thanks

Comment: It really isn't difficult enough that you need to ask a question on StackOverflow. Just loop through the array and print each of the attributes of each object in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mypost = [{"id":"i01","name":"jack","phone":"123123"},{"id":"i02","name":"john","phone":"123123"},{"id":"i03","name":"jane","phone":"123123"}]

var mm = mypost[0].id // return i01

var mm1 = mypost[1].name // return john

var mm2 = mypost[2].phone // return 123123(phone3)
```

take a look here to check the way to **iterate an array**: [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-a-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Refer below example and apply. Try it once...

```
var obj = { x: '1', a: '2', b: '3'};
var items = Object.keys(obj);
items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item + '=' + obj[item]);
});
```

its't that much difficult to solve, understand the array concept and iterate concept and apply.

Refer below link for reference of node.js document

http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html